# fatal: does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git, deploy

Estou tentando configurar um repositório Git privado em hospedagem compartilhada via SSH.

Faço todo o processo de configurar as chaves etc,e dando `git init` no repositório mas quando eu coloco

```
git remote add deploy ssh://USUARIO@IP-DO-SERVIDOR:2222/public_html/wordpress-studies
```

Na hora de dar `git push -u deploy master` aparece:

> fatal: '/public_html/wordpress-studies' does not appear to be a git
>   repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

O que isso significa?

EDIT:

Ok... o que eu tava errando era que eu não sabia a diferença entre o repositório e e pasta que tinha a arvore de trabalho da qual receberia os arquivos do repositório bare. Porém ainda não consegui resolver o problema.

O que eu fiz até agora? Criei um repositório na pasta fora do public_html do site chamada "wordpress-studies.git". Nela apliquei o comando "git init --bare"; feito isso, criei e editei o arquivo post-receive com:

```
#!/bin/sh
  echo "********************"
  echo "Post receive hook: Updating website"
  echo "********************"

  GIT_WORK_TREE=/public_html/wordpress-studies
```

Salvei e tornei executavel com "chmod +x hook/post-receive." e 
    git remote add deploy ssh://MEUSERVIDOR/home/protodes/wordpress-studies.git

E depois...

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:rafandrade/wordpressstudies.git
```

quando eu dou "git push deploy master" aparece isso aqui:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 470 bytes | 470.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 1 (delta 0)
To bitbucket.org:rafandrade/wordpressstudies.git
ec26746..e1b4c86  master -> master
```

Porém quando vou conferir a pasta não contém os arquivos que foram adicionados no commit

Comment: Você esta tentando apontar um caminho "fisico" como se fosse um repositório?

Comment: A 'public_html' está no diretório raiz? O caminho '/public_html/wordpress-studies' começa com '/' que significa o diretório raiz.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu básicamente criei uma pasta na minha hospedagem e dei "git init" para que pudesse versionar o que eu fizesse lá e pensava que isso era a definição de repositório, mas lendo mais vi q não é. Estou lendo mais sobre o assunto aqui...

Comment: editei o post, relatando os passos mais detalhadamente